# Is Sharia law man-made?

Tags: sharia

I heard it is.
I heard that the Quran only states what is wrong (adultery, stealing, killing, etc.), but it doesn't establish any punishment for it. So some men decided to assign stoning to the crime of adultery, cutting the hand to the crime of stealing, and so on.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

There are different kinds of punishments in Islam, there are [hodouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudud), which are fixed by God, they apply on theft, zina, Hirabah , drinking alcohol, accusing someone of illicit sex but failing to present enough evidence (not sure if there are more sins in this category).

There are also [Qisas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qisas) and Diyya, which apply on murder, or when the criminal deals body injuries to the victim.
From the Quran:

> وَكَتَبْنَا عَلَيْهِمْ فِيهَا أَنَّ النَّفْسَ بِالنَّفْسِ وَالْعَيْنَ بِالْعَيْنِ وَالْأَنْفَ بِالْأَنْفِ وَالْأُذُنَ بِالْأُذُنِ وَالسِّنَّ بِالسِّنِّ وَالْجُرُوحَ قِصَاصٌ ۚ فَمَنْ تَصَدَّقَ بِهِ فَهُوَ كَفَّارَةٌ لَهُ ۚ وَمَنْ لَمْ يَحْكُمْ بِمَا أَنْزَلَ اللَّهُ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الظَّالِمُونَ
>
> And We ordained for them therein a life for a life, an eye for an eye, a nose for a nose, an ear for an ear, a tooth for a tooth, and for wounds is legal retribution. But whoever gives [up his right as] charity, it is an expiation for him. And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed – then it is those who are the wrongdoers. (Verse [5:45](http://legacy.quran.com/5/45))

For example, in case of murder, the family of the victim can choose between forgiving the victim, or killing him (of course, it's the governor's job), in case of body injuries, the victim can do the same body injuries to the sinner.

If the sin does not fall in the previous two categories, then there is Tazir [تعزير](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1/) (the word Tazir means to educate in form of a reprimand or reproach), which is a punishment that is not stated in the Quran or the Sunna, it's man-made, the governors are free to choose the appropriate one (depending on the sin), it can be prison, a fine, flogging, banishment, and execution in some cases, more information about Tazir, with examples of sins that Tazir punishes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tazir).

Only Tazir is man-made.

Comment: What is tazir, please explain/elaborate?

Comment: Tazir means "to give education", it's a kind of punishements that is not fixed by the islamic law, the government is free to define it (it will depend on the severity of the sin), it applies for any sin that does not fall in the previous two categories (Hudud and Qisas), read more about it  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tazir) (there are some examples).

Comment: Should be more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Every punishment has it's own separate evidences(daleel) whither it is from Quran or from the prophet hadeeth, Muslims later grouped these punishments  together and named them all as the "sharia law". and since every punishment of them has it is own evidences, scholars  have differed on some of them.

For example cutting the hand to the crime of stealing **has a clear unambiguous evidence** (دليل - daleel) from the **Quran** [5:38](http://legacy.quran.com/5/38)

> وَالسَّارِقُ وَالسَّارِقَةُ فَاقْطَعُوا أَيْدِيَهُمَا جَزَاءً بِمَا كَسَبَا نَكَالًا مِّنَ اللَّهِ ۗ وَاللَّهُ عَزِيزٌ حَكِيمٌ (38) فَمَن تَابَ مِن بَعْدِ ظُلْمِهِ وَأَصْلَحَ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ يَتُوبُ عَلَيْهِ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ(39)
>
> [As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in recompense for what they committed as a deterrent [punishment] from Allah . And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.(38) But whoever repents after his wrongdoing and reforms, indeed, Allah will turn to him in forgiveness. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.(38)

But don't forget that there are many rules that govern these situations before you can go ahead and cut peoples hands! , for example, we should first define "the thief" , when we can prove that the person is a thief? and who is going to do the cutting? and how to do it? Of curse it is not us, it is **the job of the governments of our countries**.  these details and rules are taken care of by the scholars, not us, you and me -the public Muslims-.

---

*please be aware that I'm not a scholar or mofty I just told you what I know, so please wait until a scholar tell us his word.*

Answer (score 0):

Well you are asking two different questions, for the first part Quran has set punishments for most of the wrongdoings. For the other question:

> Is Sharia law man-made?

I would say as Karen Armstrong and other famous historians prove that the "Sharia Law" came after the death of the Prophet (SAW), so Yes it is a man-made script based on Quran and Sunnah. Which means that though it follows most of it's principles from the Quran and Sunnah, it's fundamental form is man-made.

Answer (score -6):

No. Allah has directly and Indirectly says in the quran about Islamic punishment.

For example, in the Quran Allah says:- "If anyone do Jina they kill him/her throwing stone if they are married."

Comment: No , stoning is not mentioned in Quran, however it is exist in the hadeeths